# Strategy to recognize and solve sequence and series problems?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, soft-question

I've been reading my Stewart Calculus book and I honestly find most of the coverage of sequences and series easy to grasp (excluding power series, Taylor and Maclauren since we haven't covered those just yet).

However, when the book guides me to a test to use to solve a problem I don't have an issue, but if I'm given a bunch of problems and told to choose a test to use I honestly have no idea where to begin.

How can I intuitively know how to attack a given problem?  I realize the thought process is quite similar to integration, but I still feel like integration is much easier than determining convergence and divergence of a sequence/series.

Comment: You need some experience to realise which series will fail or succeed easily which test in your toolkit. It greatly helps to _know_ your tools, it's ups and downs.
For example Leibniz' criteria has a very specific condition, but is usually easy to apply if you meet such a series, same for telescoping.
Comparison test requires the knowledge of a bunch of con- or divergent series but then allows quite rough estimates for results.

Comment: Generally you can hardly learn this better than by doing excercises and asking for alternative tests on M.SE if you happen to see a series which you suspect could be show to con/ diverge more easily than you have been able to.

Comment: @AlexR so a given problem could have multiple tests that might work?  I guess my thinking is on this is very black/white; meaning I feel there is only one test that will tell me convergence or divergence.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: This certainly is. The question to ask is _which_ test is _easier_ to apply. In fact, all tests with the same results on con/ divergence MUST yield the same result, if there is a way to apply them. Think about comparison test vs. Leibniz, I'll post an example as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$L = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$
This qualifies for both, comparison and Leibnitz:
Leibniz is applicable because $\frac1{n^2}$ is a non-increasing, positive null-sequence in $n$
And comparison yields
$$|L| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left| \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \right| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6$$

---

Worth noting here is, that using comparison as an Idea, we have even proved *absolute convergence*, which is stronger than plain convergence of Leibniz, but was a little bit more work.

---

A few general steps are:

1. Is $(a_n)_n$ even a null-sequence?
2. Can I prove absolute summability (then I won't have to worry about signs)?
   This allows for lazy estimates like $\sin, \cos \le 1$ but cannot prove divergence
3. Is Leibnitz applicable (if alternating)?
4. Do the terms look like telescoping?
   Something like $a_n = f(n) - f(n+a)$
5. Does the series look like another series, which I could compare it to?
   Most notably $\sum\limits_{n=a}^\infty \frac1{n^\alpha}$, converging iff $\Re\alpha > 1$
6. Are the coefficients "nice" in a way that I can use integral comparison?
7. ....

Comment: Thank you so much!  This list is helpful!

Comment: @inquisitor Happy to help, I added a little elaboration and an important first check :)

Comment: I meant so ask you how you got $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: @inquisitor I considered this well-known. For a proof, look over at google or here; this question was asked multiple times already :) //
EDIT: [Mathworld article on $\zeta(2)$, Basel problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html)